# ss is slow than netstat on centos 6.6/7.1

Tags: linux, sockets, centos

here is my test script

```
echo "=====ss===="
time ss -o state established | wc -l

echo "====netstat===="
time netstat -ant | grep EST | wc -l
```

and the output is:

```
[root@lab8106 ~]# ./test_network.sh 
=====ss====
268

real    0m0.212s
user    0m0.183s
sys     0m0.033s
====netstat====
169

real    0m0.026s
user    0m0.009s
sys     0m0.025s
```

as i have read many blogs and they said "ss" is much more faster than "netstat",
BUT my test result above confused me a lot. what's should i do to dig deeper on it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot `-n` for `ss`, so you're effectively doing reverse DNS lookups for every IP, which definitely prolongs the execution time.

Comment: yeah, i add "-n" it really as fast as netstat, thanks